# Ошибка при запуске приложение CriminalIntent (книга "Android. Программирование для профессионалов")

Tags: java, android, gradle

При попытке запустить приложение выдается ошибка "Приложение остановлено", а в логах появляется ошибка:

```
11-27 23:07:56.394 4318-4318/com.bignerdranch.android.criminalintent E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Process: com.bignerdranch.android.criminalintent, PID: 4318
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method getFont(Landroid/content/Context;ILandroid/util/TypedValue;ILandroid/widget/TextView;)Landroid/graphics/Typeface; in class Landroid/support/v4/content/res/ResourcesCompat; or its super classes (declaration of 'android.support.v4.content.res.ResourcesCompat' appears in /data/app/com.bignerdranch.android.criminalintent-2/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk)
at android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getFont(TintTypedArray.java:119)
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextHelper.updateTypefaceAndStyle(AppCompatTextHelper.java:208)
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextHelper.loadFromAttributes(AppCompatTextHelper.java:110)
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextHelperV17.loadFromAttributes(AppCompatTextHelperV17.java:38)
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:81)
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:71)
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:67)
at android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.setTitle(Toolbar.java:753)
at android.support.v7.widget.ToolbarWidgetWrapper.setTitleInt(ToolbarWidgetWrapper.java:261)
at android.support.v7.widget.ToolbarWidgetWrapper.setWindowTitle(ToolbarWidgetWrapper.java:243)
at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.setWindowTitle(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:621)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onTitleChanged(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:631)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:328)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:284)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
at com.bignerdranch.android.criminalintent.SingleFragmentActivity.onCreate(SingleFragmentActivity.java:14)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5966)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2408)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2517)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:162)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1412)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:189)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5529)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:956)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:751)
```

Comment: support library у вас какой версии? gradle скрипт покажите.

Comment: @Suvitruf
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.0.1'
}

Comment: До 27 версии обновитесь.

Comment: спасибо, обновление версии библиотеки помогло

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно обновиться до 27 версии.