# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError в android при работе с recyclerView

Tags: java

Доброй ночи, напоролся на `NoSuchMenthodError` при компиляции, искал на англ stackoverflow, говорят, что проблема с либами, но (вроде бы) с либами всё хорошо, в чём может быть проблема? Спасибо.

```
Process: konyuh.vadim.crimeactivity, PID: 4505
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method getFont(Landroid/content/Context;ILandroid/util/TypedValue;ILandroid/widget/TextView;)Landroid/graphics/Typeface; in class Landroid/support/v4/content/res/ResourcesCompat; or its super classes (declaration of 'android.support.v4.content.res.ResourcesCompat' appears in /data/app/konyuh.vadim.crimeactivity-1/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk)
    at android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getFont(TintTypedArray.java:119)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextHelper.updateTypefaceAndStyle(AppCompatTextHelper.java:208)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextHelper.loadFromAttributes(AppCompatTextHelper.java:110)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextHelperV17.loadFromAttributes(AppCompatTextHelperV17.java:38)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:81)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:71)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:67)
    at android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.setTitle(Toolbar.java:753)
    at android.support.v7.widget.ToolbarWidgetWrapper.setTitleInt(ToolbarWidgetWrapper.java:261)
    at android.support.v7.widget.ToolbarWidgetWrapper.setWindowTitle(ToolbarWidgetWrapper.java:243)
    at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.setWindowTitle(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:621)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onTitleChanged(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:631)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:328)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:284)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
    at konyuh.vadim.crimeactivity.SingleFragmentActivity.onCreate(SingleFragmentActivity.java:20)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
E/ResourcesManager: failed to add asset path /data/app/konyuh.vadim.crimeactivity-2/base.apk
```

Comment: Возможно [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47126127/5330439) решение вашей проблемы.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Ошибка при запуске приложение CriminalIntent (книга "Android. Программирование для профессионалов")](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/750477/%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-criminalintent-%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b0-android-%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b4)

Comment: До 27 версии обновитесь.

Comment: Покажите свой лейаут, у вас похоже проблема с `android:tint`

Comment: Проблема была в том, что библиотека не подгружалась через settings, подгрузил через build gradle